# How to send a list to query (IN condition)

Tags: jasper-reports

i'm working with iReport 5.5, and i'm using a query to get a list of cars :

When i use the condition like this :

```
and a.id_modele IN (1,2,10,11)
```

It works fine but when i add the List that i fill from iReport :

```
and a.id_modele IN ($P!{MODELE})
```

The type of *MODELE* parameter is *java.util.List*.

i get the following error :

```
   Error filling print... Error executing SQL statement for : report name 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.io.InputStream.<init>(java.lang.String)      
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2810)     
... 
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERREUR: erreur de syntaxe sur ou près de « [ »  
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1592)
```

Comment: What's your parameter type ?!? (MODELE)

Comment: Change the type of MODELE from List to String and see if it change something

Comment: @YagamiLight i changed it and it works

Comment: Awesome I will wright an answer

Comment: @BillyHope It is better to use `$X{}` in your case (using List)

Comment: @AlexK don't think it is a duplicate one the problem isn't from the query it self it's from the parameter type

Comment: It is exactly the same problem. The parameter of List type - it is valid type :)